# Pass variables from a while to another while

Tags: php, sql, foreach, while-loop

I have a little problem with this form.
On the fprm page my code is:

```
         <form action="?act=process" method="post">
         <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE day = '$day' ORDER BY ID ASC";
         $hours = mysql_query($sql);
         while ($hour = mysql_fetch_array($hours)) { ?>     

         <input type="text" name="course" value="<?=$hour[course]?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$hour[ID]?>">

         <?php } ?>

         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

On the process page looks like this:

```
         while($id = each($_POST['id']) && $course = each($_POST['course'])) 
         { 
         //echo "ID $id AND course $course<br/>";
         }
```

All I need to do is to pass all variables in a while to update each of them in my sql database.

The error I get is: **Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /path_domain**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you try to use id/course data as array, but you pass just strings. In order to avoid it, just make you form fields as arrays by adding `[]` to the fields names:

```
     <input type="text" name="course[]" value="<?=$hour[course]?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?=$hour[ID]?>">
```

Comment: The error disappear now by the output looks like this ID 1 AND course Array
ID 1 AND course Array
ID 1 AND course Array

Comment: @Adrian As you can see at http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php , each returns array, not a string/number, that's why you get `Array` in the output. I suggest to replace `each` with `foreach` like the following:

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $course = $_POST['course'][$key];
    echo "Id is $id AND course $course<br/>";
}

Answer (score 0):

By adding the [] brackets after the name of the fields.

```
<form action="?act=process" method="post">
     <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE day = '$day' ORDER BY ID ASC";
     $hours = mysql_query($sql);
     while ($hour = mysql_fetch_array($hours)) { ?>     

     <input type="text" name="course[]" value="<?=$hour[course]?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?=$hour[ID]?>">

     <?php } ?>

     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```